# iOS: Auto-delete New Database Entries After 1 Hour

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, server-side

I'm building an iOS app that allows for "social post-it notes." You and your friends can create a shared wall upon which you all can post notes.

I would like each post-it note to have a "lifespan" of 1 hour. For example, let's say you post a note at 3:00. From 3:00 to 3:59, you and your friends can see the note. At 4:00, the note is automatically deleted, and you and your friends can no longer see it.

I have built everything EXCEPT the auto-delete feature--I'm just not sure how to implement this kind of thing. I'm not sure if something like this can even be implemented client-side (in the app itself). It seems that some sort of server-side process would have to run continuously, comparing the timestamp of each note with the current time, and then deleting the note if the difference between the timestamp and the current time is greater than 1 hour. (Keep in mind, I'm currently using [Parse](http://parse.com) as my back-end.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why you must delete it? Just make it no longer visible to the user on client side is not enough?

Comment: I guess that could work: each time the user refreshes the post-it wall, I run a query for the appropriate post-it notes; I could compare the timestamps of the returned post-it notes with the current time, and only choose to display the appropriate ones.

But this doesn't seem very efficient or scalable. For one, what if, after a while, my query returns 1000 notes, but only 10 are actually eligible to show? Secondly, my database would be increasingly and unnecessarily large by continuing to store all of these unneeded notes.

Comment: You could also delete it from the database during querying.

Comment: If not, then set a timer for the delete event. However, it's inevitable to do the refresh on the contents periodically/ by trigger